# Matching 2 cells from 2 sheets and return value from another cell

Tags: excel-formula

Trying to make a document with 2 sheets, one is a main and another one is like a database.

if Sheet1 A2 and B1 match Sheet2 A2 and B1 return value B2 from Sheet2 to Sheet1 B2 cell.

[image: Sheet1]

[image: Sheet2]

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!B2,MATCH(Sheet2!A2&Sheet2!B1,INDEX(Sheet1!A2&Sheet1!B1,0),0))
```

Comment: `=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$H$5,MATCH($A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$4,0),MATCH(B$2,Sheet2!$B$1:$H$1,0))`